# How can i navigate the Users relationships via the controller.user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

If i add a relationship to my user entity in The IdentityFramewrk Code first model, is it possible to easily navigate the Controller.User's relationship from within a Controller's Action.

i.e.
When debugging my controllers user property doesn't appear to have navigable properties? Do i need to cast it to something or is there a property which has the ID (Guid) which i then user to find my custom IdentityUser Object?

//model

```
public class Customer : IdentityUser
    {
        public string HomeTown { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Order> Orders{ get; set; }
    }
```

//controlleraction

```
 [Authorize]
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
        //this.User.

        return View();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `User` object to look up the current user's Id. Then you can use your `UserManager` to retrieve the actual domain object.

For example:

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var user = _userManager.FindById(userId);
```